# eas-cli: how to build with releaseChannel?

Tags: react-native, expo, release, eas

I have an environment with API_URL changed depend on releaseChannel

for example in production I want to build with API_URL="https:prod.APPNAME.com".
and for staging : API_URL="https:staging.APPNAME.com".

how can I do that using eas.json

my environment.js:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
// import {API_URL} from '@env';
import { commonProperties } from "./environments.common";

const dev_URL = "http://10.30.157.214:8080/";

const staging_URL = "https:staging.APPNAME.com";
const production_URL = "https:prod.APPNAME.com";

const environment = {
  production: false,
  dev: {
    apiUrl: dev_URL,
    ...commonProperties,
  },
  staging: {
    apiUrl: staging_URL,
    ...commonProperties,
  },
  prod: {
    apiUrl: production_URL,
    ...commonProperties,
  },
};

const getEnvVars = (env = Constants.manifest!.releaseChannel) => {
  // What is __DEV__ ?
  // This variable is set to true when react-native is running in Dev mode.
  // __DEV__ is true when run locally, but false when published.
  if (__DEV__) {
    return environment.dev;
  } else if (env === "staging") {
    return environment.staging;
  } else if (env === "prod") {
    return environment.prod;
  }
  // return environment.prod;
};

export default getEnvVars;
```

my eas.json:

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "releaseChannel": "staging"
    },
    "productionTest": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      },
      "releaseChannel": "prod"
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "releaseChannel": "prod"
    }
  }
}
```

when i use the command: `eas build -p android --profile productionTest` the build done with `Constants.manifest!.releaseChannel` undefined.

is there's any solution to this problem?